# How to pass MVC model which includes large list as Ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I just spent a fruitless morning trying the various "workarounds" that have been suggested - usually for more specific cases than the one I'm after. All I'm trying to do is pass an ASP.NET MVC model using the JQuery load method. It seems to like

```
  var myModel = {
            Message: "@Model.Message",
            PageNumber: "@Model.PageNumber",
            UserList: ["@Model.UserList"] }
```

insofar as this allows me to successfully post two out of the three fields. However, I get null for the list. This is predictable as I'm not writing the list in the correct format. But how *would* I write it given that the number of users is large and indeterminate so I can't fill out each entry "by hand"? I *might* get it working through a Razor monstrosity, but I want to avoid that if physically possible.

Surely there's an easy way to do this? Ultimately all I'm trying to do is convert a model containing a large list into a JSON object in Javascript.

Comment: What is the point of this - `@Model.someValue` will be just posting back the original unchanged model! (you already know what it is on the server). And You cannot assign a collection to a single property (its just generating `UserList: System.Collection.Generic.List[....`) What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to call some action using Ajax without losing the data so it seems quite a natural way to proceed. The alternative would be calling an action and losing all the existing data - not something I want to do. As I said in the above post I'm just trying to post the entire model without losing the list. I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: Dont! You know what the model is on the server, Just get it again as you did in the GET method (all you need to post is whatever ID value you initially used). You have already stated the _users is large_ so your just degrading performance by sending all this unnecessary data across the wire.

Comment: please go through stephen muecke's comment, you are sending the same model data to the controller, no change at all, then what is the use of it?

Comment: I have the list already. Why would I want to slow down the application by retrieving the large list again from the database? If I don't need to do this I can't understand why I would do it. Surely the thing I'm suggesting shouldn't be that difficult?

Comment: I guess you need to do some more research. Get the data again. Store it in session if your concerned about hitting the database again (although that might suggest a poorly designed database)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. Nor does it explain why passing a fairly standard model through Ajax ought to be so difficult or out of the ordinary that the subject needs to be changed to architecture and motivation. I can think of a hundred legitimate scenarios in which you might need to pass a model using Ajax which also includes a list which is too cumbersome to write every entry by hand.

Comment: Why cant you just return a `JSONResult` from your controller like   `Return Json(yourmodel)`

Comment: Good question - I probably could have done that! My only excuse can be that I'm new to MVC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two answers above (Session data and returning a JSONResult) probably would have worked for my purposes (only dimly knew about them - still learning the ropes here!). As far as the answer to the question is concerned, however, I ended up solving the problem by means of the aforementioned Razor monstrosity. Namely,

```
var myModel = {
        Message: "@Model.Message",
        PageNumber: "@Model.PageNumber",
        UserList: [

            @{
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserList.Count; i++)
    {
        @:{ Name : "@Model.UserList[i].Name ",
            @: Organization : "@Model.UserList[i].Organization "
            @:},
                }
    }        ]  };
```

Edit: I don't particularly understand why people are downvoting when none of the other comments actually answered the question that was put. I don't think it's unreasonable or remarkable to wonder how you can pass a fairly standard list using Ajax without writing out every single entry by hand.